# c++: Operations order in for loop increment part

Tags: c++, specifications

Consider the following piece of code:

```
int totalLength = 0;
int partLength = 0;
for(; totalLength < SOME_CONST; totalLength += partLength, partLength = 0)
{
    //partLength may be increased here
}
```

In this particular case, can I assume that partLength will be set to 0 AFTER it will be added to totalLength (so if partLength will be increased in the loop body, I won't be adding 0 to totalLength at the end of the loop)? I read about c++ sequences and such, but didn't find any clear answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The left hand side of the comma operator is sequenced before the right hand side. `totalLength += partLength` will be fully evaluated before it performs `partLength = 0`.

Comment: So it isn't implementation dependent? I was afraid it is, thus that question.

Comment: @PookyFan It isn't. You can read more about it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator), too.